# T-SQL - select XML node values, or NULL if the nodes don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have an XML that looks like below. As of now if both A and B nodes are coming in the XML, I can easily map their attribute i.e. `type="A-type"` and `type="B-type"`.

I'm stuck at a scenario when `<B>` node may not be present in the XML and then too, I need to get `<A>` node attribute i.e. `type="A-type"`, but current logic returns me no rows. Please help how to achieve this.

**Please note** that `<B>` can come any number of times under `<A>`, that's why we have to use the path `Root/A/B`. Since occurrence of `<B>` is not predicted, I can't change the path.

Example 1 (`<B>` is present):

```
DECLARE @myXML XML = 
'<Root>
<A type="A-type">
<B type="B-type"></B>
</A>
</Root>'

SELECT 
  N.value('(../@type)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'), 
  N.value('(@type)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') 
FROM @myXML.nodes('Root/A/B') AS X(N)
```

[image: Result Example 1]

Example 2 (`<B>` is not present):

```
DECLARE @myXML XML = 
'<Root>
<A type="A-type">
</A>
</Root>'

SELECT 
  N.value('(../@type)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'), 
  N.value('(@type)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') 
FROM @myXML.nodes('Root/A/B') AS X(N)
```

[image: Result Example 2]

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  x1.A.value('@type','VARCHAR(100)'), 
  x2.B.value('@type','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM
  @myXML.nodes('/Root/A[1]') AS x1(A)
  OUTER APPLY @myXML.nodes('/Root/A[1]/B') AS x2(B)
```

With

```
<Root>
  <A type="A-type">
    <B type="B-type 1"></B>
    <B type="B-type 2"></B>
    <B type="B-type 3"></B>
  </A>
</Root>
```

it returns

```
A-type  B-type 1
A-type  B-type 2
A-type  B-type 3
```

with

```
<Root>
  <A type="A-type">
    <B type="B-type"></B>
  </A>
</Root>
```

it returns

```
A-type  B-type
```

and with

```
<Root>
  <A type="A-type">
  </A>
</Root>
```

it returns

```
A-type  NULL
```